# Typescript factory of generic interface in

Tags: typescript, generics, factory

I'm creating a factory like this:

```
interface IOperator<T> {
  parse(arg: string): T;
  doSomething(value: T): void;
}
```

2 operators:

```
class StringOperator implements IOperator<string> {
  parse(arg: string) {
    return arg;
  }
  doSomething(value: string) { /* some logic */}
}

class NumberOperator implements IOperator<number> {
  parse(arg: string) {
    return parseInt(arg, 10);
  }
  doSomething(value: number) { /* some logic */}
}
```

the factory:

```
const operatorMap = {
  STRING: StringOperator,
  NUMBER: NumberOperator,
};

export const supportedOperators = Object.keys(operatorMap);

type OperatorMap = typeof operatorMap;
export type Operators = keyof OperatorMap;

type Tuples<T> = T extends Operators
  ? [T, InstanceType<OperatorMap[T]>]
  : never;
type SingleOperators<K> = [K] extends (K extends Operators ? [K] : never)
  ? K
  : never;
type ClassType<A extends Operators> = Extract<Tuples<Operators>, [A, any]>[1];

export class OperatorFactory {
  static create<K extends Operators>(k: SingleOperators<K>): ClassType<K> {
    return new operatorMap[k]();
  }
}
```

and use them like this:

```
const operator = OperatorFactory.create(operatorName);
const theValue = operator.parse(theArgument);
return operator.doSomething(theValue);
```

I get the message:

```
const theValue: string | number
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Please check [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAO05gPZQA8AKgHzIDeAUMspnFAM4QAUDA5gFzKNhSjsAlN2IBuGsgAmeAMp4AthDAALASwBucADYBXCCOHJ1eYJPEBfKlQRa4jRshl8BWHPijJg8zFoiLwDhjYULgEhLz8IOzk1LT0TKwc3BECgpQStFBKOlAgyBzitJa00nKKKmqauvo8zlFpFMgA9ABUPAooWnjswAjILU2Wlta29sgAcjryAEbQriHunt6+-mCB86FEIFOzUDES8cxsUFy1kULptJnZuXQMzKjgx+wANMgAjAAMgoXIxVKyDoVKIabR6bjbGbQBrNNqMDrILo9PoDIZWBB4EC8ZB4YKbACycEwyAAvJdHMQAEqocYAcW4TnOG3cLwk4wAqviAEIAUUp3EmUKgzIIrPM4ioEAAHpgCGBkBisfLGDpMLKoJBJCKmKTkOhpgArCAIMAAOgA1hAAJ6MFi4twEQmYH5WMBW7B6vHuJ26t3YPAwHFex1E8R+lDahxky1WgOeh1QJ0S8PIYiq3yMEjkMnEZDSyAgSQOSMSAD8yAA2sQ3o9eHAQEhiO6IIRtU6qwBdUgdiQQiDqaBh5uOAS+SOEADS2crE47ealBaLyBYE-ni+LwZ15Yrs+QfYHUEEZeQE97yBA-cHVBTAGFRowm9hCABBNcQQsbhOMac8hchE0kOmECZpGpBvBWz5vPWVpdhW7wdhK0rqvKNh2J+CwEAAYog7hWuSdZgL0CpZLgLarvm75LqBLDmgyo4QOOU6GHeaGPmR+xXMgWRgDkeQXgA7kGCbtuaHYsC6RRUMMMA6A2hGYgCxCqCC9oYVA4xwIo3CRm8KgQM+JxTO+YDJHUFyxAqmLYqpmy6tq2EmgQVqmggJGQHam4aYoEmWUqyB6QAamCKBkjZ7imocrB6QZ7BGeAPncbxQlqaapRAsp7AsIFwUusMVBAA) for details.

I assume the issue is `theValue` can be `string | number` but `.doSomething()` only accept one value type.

If I let `.doSomething(theValue: unknown)` then do the conversion inside `doSomething` it will work, but it's not what I expected.

What should I do to make this pattern work in good practice pattern?

Thanks,